# ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to set the target and then scale my features. However I am getting an error:

```
# Set a variable (features) with the names of all the features BUT the target variable.

X = data.drop("diagnosis_result",1)   #Feature Matrix
y = data["diagnosis_result"]          #Target Variable
data.head()

print(f"The list of columns that represent features is:\n{X}")
print(f"So, we have {len(X)} dimensions in our feature vectors.")

scaler = RobustScaler().fit(data[X])
data[X] = scaler.transform(data[X]).round(2)

print()
data.head()
```

Comment: which line is the error?

Answer (score 1):

you can reshape it target variable and featurematrix ..

```
X = data.drop("diagnosis_result",1).reshape(-1,1)   #Feature Matrix
y = data["diagnosis_result"]..reshape(-1,1)          #Target Variable
```